# Submitting under review paper in the admission process, Is it ok?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions

The university I am applying to has an option in which I can upload my under review/accepted papers. Is it okay to do it considering the fact that the paper is not published yet?
My under review paper has the same topic as one of the research topics in a lab in that university.

Answer (score 2):

If the university says it is fine, then it is fine. Label them correctly, of course. But even if they don't specifically ask for them then a person can submit them as "under review" and it will be properly understood. One might even list work that is well along, but not yet submitted as "work in progress".

Just be honest in labelling. And for those under review, say which journals/conferences are currently reviewing them.

Comment: Hmm yeah, but do I have to get permission from my master's advisors (the co-authors)?

Comment: @sandra just ask them, they're unlikely to say no.

Comment: Probably good to ask, but I don't think technically necessary. You aren't "publishing" them by sharing with an admissions committee.

Comment: @astronat actually one of them might disagree. He even made me cc him in the email in which I sent the paper to a distinguished well known professor.

Comment: Actually, I think a cc is just courtesy. But as @astronat suggests, ask. If you get pushback then maybe another of the authors, if they have authority, can intervene.

Comment: Full agree to the first paragraph. The second is controversial: quite a few people dislike naming the target journal of under-revew papers. That's because it can be read to suggest that just submitting to a particular journal is an accomplishment (which it isn't) and creates an association to that journal (which does not exist yet).